# Abrir menu dropdown y cerrar otro dropdown en ipad tablet

Tags: html, bootstrap, scss

Tuve un problema que al momento de abrir dropdown en iPad y luego voy a abrir otro, este solo hacía que el que estaba abierto se cerrara y el que quería abrir no se abría al oprimir por primera vez, lo que me obligaba a oprimir dos veces el dropdown.

Comment: @lois6b ahora espero que estemos como corresponde, solo quiero sumar puntos, espero sirva. saludos y gracias

Comment: Sumar puntos es válido, cada uno aporta por sus motivos. Pero las publicaciones serán de mejor aceptación si se busca resolver problemas comúnes. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución solo con css, aquí el ejemplo.

**HTML**

`<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle tab-menu-link" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">Otros servicios<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="first" href="javascript:;">Giros</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Equifax</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Pago de cuentas</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Recargas</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>`

**SCSS**

```
button.btn.btn-default.dropdown-toggle.tab-menu-link {
  &+.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 80%;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: -126px;
    max-width: 256px;

    @media (max-width: $md-device ){
      margin-right: -115px;
    }
  }
  &:hover{
    @media (max-width: $md-device){
      .glyphicon.glyphicon-menu-down {
        &:before {
          content: "\e260";
        }
      }
      &+.dropdown-menu {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        top: 100%;

        @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
          right: 0;
        }
      }
      &:after,
      &:hover:after {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
      }
    }
  }
  &[aria-expanded="true"] {
    .glyphicon.glyphicon-menu-down {
      &:before {
        content: "\e260";
      }
    }
    &+.dropdown-menu {
      left: auto;
      right: 0;
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      top: 100%;

      @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
        right: 0;
      }
    }
    &:after,
    &:hover:after {
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
header();
});
function header() {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
}
```